# ceph mds service fails to start centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, ceph

I'm trying to create ceph-mds manually on Centos 7 on Ceph Nautilus 14.2.19.
first i created a folder inside `/var/lib/ceph/mds` in the format of `<clusterid>-mds.<hostid>`
then ran the following commands:

```
ceph-authtool --create-keyring /var/lib/ceph/mds/ceph-mds.<hostid>/keyring --gen-key -n mds.<hostid>
ceph auth add mds.<hostid> osd "allow rwx" mds "allow *" mon "allow profile mds" -i /var/lib/ceph/mds/ceph-mds.<hostid>/keyring
```

Then i changed user permissions of contents of `/var/lib/ceph/mds/` to `ceph:ceph`.
When i check the keyring and the keyring added on `ceph auth list`  for mds i can confirm they are matching.
However when I run systemctl start ceph-mds@mds. the daemon doesnt start and on journalctl i get the following error output:

```
Apr 20 11:38:14 <hostid> ceph-mds[44742]: 2021-04-20 11:38:14.592 7f53bcaef700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2]
Apr 20 11:38:14 <hostid> ceph-mds[44742]: failed to fetch mon config (--no-mon-config to skip).
```

The entire output of systemctl status ceph-mds@mds.:

```
● ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service - Ceph metadata server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-mds@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2021-04-20 12:28:15 +03; 11min ago
  Process: 15564 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ceph-mds -f --cluster ${CLUSTER} --id %i --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 15564 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service entered failed state.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service failed.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: Stopped Ceph metadata server daemon.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: Failed to start Ceph metadata server daemon.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service entered failed state.
Apr 20 12:28:15 <hostid> systemd[1]: ceph-mds@mds.<hostid>.service failed.
```

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Is the mds daemon colocated with other ceph daemons or is it a standalone machine? Does it have at least a minimal ceph.conf?

Comment: I actually resolved this problem but forgot i post this question here my bad. Apparently the problem was because of wrong directory naming inside /var/lib/ceph/mds . After changing that and restarting the service it was fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying, I guess you could close the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Apparently the problem was because of wrong directory naming inside `/var/lib/ceph/mds` . After changing that and restarting the service it was fixed.